# sqlite database error for

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-database

I am trying to create a application  where i need to create two table register n details . i want registered user can login and then they can save their details. but can any one tell me how to establish this connection between these two table. i tried doing it with like this but getting error.

(PasswordKeeperDb.java)

```
public class PasswordKeeperDb {
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private DbHelper dbHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "PasswordKeeper";
private static final String REGISTER_TABLE_NAME = "RegisterTable";
private static final String DETAIL_TABLE_NAME = "DetailsTable";


private static String FIRST_NAME = "firstName", LAST_NAME = "lastName", EMAIL = "email",
        PASSWORD = "password", LOGIN_ID = "loginId", DETAIL_ID = "detailsId", TITLE = "title";


private static final String REGISTER_TABLE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
        + REGISTER_TABLE_NAME
        + "("
        + LOGIN_ID
        + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , "
        + FIRST_NAME
        + " VARCHAR(80) , "
        + LAST_NAME
        + " VARCHAR(80) , "
        + EMAIL
        + " VARCHAR(80) , "
        + PASSWORD
        + " VARCHAR(80) ) ";

private static final String DETAIL_TABLE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
        + DETAIL_TABLE_NAME
        + "("
        + DETAIL_ID
        + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , "
        + LOGIN_ID
        + " INTEGER ,"
        + TITLE
        + " VARCHAR(80) , "
        + EMAIL
        + " VARCHAR(80) , "
        + PASSWORD
        + " VARCHAR(10) , )";



private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL(REGISTER_TABLE_CREATE);
        db.execSQL(DETAIL_TABLE_CREATE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    }
}


public PasswordKeeperDb(Context c) {
    dbHelper = new DbHelper(c);
}

public long insertRegisterTable(final RegisterModel registerModel)
        throws SQLException {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(FIRST_NAME, registerModel.getFname());
    values.put(LAST_NAME, registerModel.getLname());
    values.put(EMAIL, registerModel.getEmail());
    values.put(PASSWORD, registerModel.getPassword());
    return sqLiteDatabase.insert(REGISTER_TABLE_NAME, null, values);
}

public long insertDetailTable(final AddModel addModel)
        throws SQLException {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(LOGIN_ID, addModel.getLoginId());
    values.put(TITLE, addModel.getTitle());
    values.put(EMAIL, addModel.getEmail());
    values.put(PASSWORD, addModel.getPassword());
    return sqLiteDatabase.insert("DetailsTable", null, values);
}


public PasswordKeeperDb open() throws SQLException {
    sqLiteDatabase = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    sqLiteDatabase = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    return this;
}


public Cursor getUser(String email, String pass) {
    return sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("select * from " + REGISTER_TABLE_NAME + " where email=" + "'" + email +
            "' and password=" + "'" + pass + "'", null);
}

public Cursor getLoginId(String email) {
    return sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("select loginId from " + REGISTER_TABLE_NAME + " where email=" + "'" + email +
            "'", null);
}

public void close() {
    dbHelper.close();
}
}
```

(MainActivity.java)

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton;

ListView listView;
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
PasswordKeeperDb passwordKeeperDb;
View mView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_details, null);
final EditText mEmail  = (EditText) mView.findViewById(R.id.email);
final EditText mTitle  = (EditText) mView.findViewById(R.id.title);
final EditText  mPassword = (EditText) mView.findViewById(R.id.password);


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    floatingActionButton = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.add);

    passwordKeeperDb = new PasswordKeeperDb(this);

    floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

            mBuilder.setView(mView);
            final AlertDialog dialog = mBuilder.create();



            Button mAdd = (Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.dadd);
            mAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (mTitle.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Add Title", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    } else if (mEmail.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Add Email", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    } else if (mPassword.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Add Password!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    } else {
                        passwordKeeperDb.open();
                        AddModel addModel = new AddModel("", getLoginId(mEmail), mTitle.getText().toString(), mEmail.getText().toString(), mPassword.getText().toString());
                        Long result = passwordKeeperDb.insertDetailTable(addModel);
                        Log.d("ADB", result + "");
                        if (result > 0) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ADDED Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error Occurred !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        passwordKeeperDb.close();

                    }
                }
            });
            dialog.show();


        }
    });


}

private String getLoginId(EditText mEmail) {

    return getLoginId(this.mEmail);
}

}
```

Log Cat:

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                     Process: com.example.hope.passwordkeeper, PID: 26605
                                                                                 android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ")": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DetailsTable(detailsId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , loginId INTEGER ,title VARCHAR(80) , email VARCHAR(80) , password VARCHAR(10) , )
                                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:887)
                                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:498)
                                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
                                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
                                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1674)
                                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1605)
                                                                                     at com.example.hope.passwordkeeper.PasswordKeeperDb$DbHelper.onCreate(PasswordKeeperDb.java:69)
                                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:251)
                                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
                                                                                     at com.example.hope.passwordkeeper.PasswordKeeperDb.open(PasswordKeeperDb.java:105)
                                                                                     at com.example.hope.passwordkeeper.HomeActivity$1$1.onClick(HomeActivity.java:51)
                                                                                     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5207)
                                                                                     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21168)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

Comment: perhaps bcz of extra comma in + " VARCHAR(10) , )";

Comment: you have add comma for last column please remove comma like this  + " VARCHAR(10)  )";  for DETAIL_TABLE_CREATE

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQLiteDatabase error "sqlite: (1) near ")": syntax error"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23032024/sqlitedatabase-error-sqlite-1-near-syntax-error)

Comment: whats error you get??  after change clean project as well uninstall app then again try to run

Comment: @SuruchiSinha example of login and register with sqlite http://www.androidtutorialshub.com/android-login-and-register-with-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find the correct code:-

```
public class PasswordKeeperDb {
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private DbHelper dbHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "PasswordKeeper";
private static final String REGISTER_TABLE_NAME = "RegisterTable";
private static final String DETAIL_TABLE_NAME = "DetailsTable";


private static String FIRST_NAME = "firstName", LAST_NAME = "lastName", EMAIL = "email",
        PASSWORD = "password", LOGIN_ID = "loginId", DETAIL_ID = "detailsId", TITLE = "title";


private static final String REGISTER_TABLE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
        + REGISTER_TABLE_NAME
        + "("
        + LOGIN_ID
        + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , "
        + FIRST_NAME
        + " VARCHAR(80) , "
        + LAST_NAME
        + " VARCHAR(80) , "
        + EMAIL
        + " VARCHAR(80) , "
        + PASSWORD
        + " VARCHAR(80) ) ";

private static final String DETAIL_TABLE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
        + DETAIL_TABLE_NAME
        + "("
        + DETAIL_ID
        + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , "
        + LOGIN_ID
        + " INTEGER ,"
        + TITLE
        + " VARCHAR(80) , "
        + EMAIL
        + " VARCHAR(80) , "
        + PASSWORD
        + " VARCHAR(10) )";



private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL(REGISTER_TABLE_CREATE);
        db.execSQL(DETAIL_TABLE_CREATE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    }
}


public PasswordKeeperDb(Context c) {
    dbHelper = new DbHelper(c);
}

public long insertRegisterTable(final RegisterModel registerModel)
        throws SQLException {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(FIRST_NAME, registerModel.getFname());
    values.put(LAST_NAME, registerModel.getLname());
    values.put(EMAIL, registerModel.getEmail());
    values.put(PASSWORD, registerModel.getPassword());
    return sqLiteDatabase.insert(REGISTER_TABLE_NAME, null, values);
}

public long insertDetailTable(final AddModel addModel)
        throws SQLException {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(LOGIN_ID, addModel.getLoginId());
    values.put(TITLE, addModel.getTitle());
    values.put(EMAIL, addModel.getEmail());
    values.put(PASSWORD, addModel.getPassword());
    return sqLiteDatabase.insert("DetailsTable", null, values);
}


public PasswordKeeperDb open() throws SQLException {
    sqLiteDatabase = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    sqLiteDatabase = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    return this;
}


public Cursor getUser(String email, String pass) {
    return sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("select * from " + REGISTER_TABLE_NAME + " where email=" + "'" + email +
            "' and password=" + "'" + pass + "'", null);
}

public Cursor getLoginId(String email) {
    return sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("select loginId from " + REGISTER_TABLE_NAME + " where email=" + "'" + email +
            "'", null);
}

public void close() {
    dbHelper.close();
}
```

You have add extra comma on create detail table at the end.

Answer (score 2):

At first rectify your **DETAIL_TABLE_CREATE**

```
 private static final String DETAIL_TABLE_CREATE  =
            "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_TEAM + " ("
                    + DETAIL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ,"
                    + LOGIN_ID + " INTEGER ,"
                    + TITLE + " VARCHAR(80) ,"
                    + EMAIL + " VARCHAR(80) ,"
                    + PASSWORD + " VARCHAR(10)" + ")";
```

Then **Clean Rebuild and Uninstall OLD app** and run again